# C++: Light Weight Camera Solution

Tags: c++, windows-7, camera, mfc, photo

I am trying to come up with a very lightweight Camera program using C++. This is to be integrated as part of an existing MFC project.

Basically the MFC project lauches a form using DHTML and one of the components of the form is a button which is supposed to launch a camera to allow user to capture an image.

**Functionality of Button is as follows:**

**Requirement:** Button Clicked on Form --> Launch Back Camera on Windows 7 Tablet --> Capture Image --> Save Image (in a specified path) --> Get Saved Path (including the file name).

**Stuff Done till now:**

1. Created an working model with OpenCV. 
   **Client feedback** = Too heavy for such a simple operation
2. Tried to use cameracaptureui - No support for Windows 7 (Only Windows 8 and beyond)

Can anyone point me in the direction that I am supposed to look?

Comment: MFC isn't going to be lightweight by any stretch of the term. Maybe you should put up real requirements instead of throwing about fuzzy buzz words. At any rate, this question is way too broad for SO's Q&A format.

Comment: If Media Foundation is supported on windows 7 for tablets then it's your best option in my opinion. That and DirectShow probably.

Comment: I seem to have misquoted myself. I have an existing MFC application.Its launches a form (using DHTML) and on that form is a button which is supposed to launch the camera. Hope this clarifies the question. I will update my question accordingly

Comment: Can't you use the camera SDK directly?

Comment: @sergiol: Sorry to not have replied before, I was on the road and hence had very limited time to catch up on this. I am new to this, so are you suggesting that I call up the Camera exe directly from my code?

Comment: No. Don't  your camera have a SDK? By SDK, I mean some lib or source with callable code.

Comment: @sergiol: I am kind of a newbie here. Is there anyway I can verify that?